# Uploading file using $_FILES and PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

Today I tried for the first time to upload files to my website, but it seems that it doesn't work. I hope someone can help me, and I hope my code is readable :)

The problem is when I choose file and SUBMIT form it is not accepted because `$_FILES` is NULL

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['obrazok']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
```

UPDATED Error

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/793392545Untitled.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gj020900/www_nekonomagic/admin/admin-nove-anime.php on line 107

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/home/gj020900/tmp/php9izgwb' to 'www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/793392545Untitled.jpg' in /home/gj020900/www_nekonomagic/admin/admin-nove-anime.php on line 107
```

Shorted form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../admin/admin-nove-anime.php" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
        <label for="obrazok" class=""> Obrázok anime (Max. 3MB):</label>
        <input type="file" name="obrazok" id="obrazok" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="pridaj_anime_submit" value="Pridať anime" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP part:

```
if (isset($_POST['pridaj_anime_submit'])) {
    // skontroluje sa ci sa subor ulozil ak ano pokracuje ak nie napise chybu
    $uploaddir = '/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['obrazok']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['obrazok']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // prva cast formy
        $nazov = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['nazov']);
        $rok = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['rok']);
        $pocet = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['pocet']);
        $preklad = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['preklad']);
        $stav = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['stav']);

        $sql_vloz_anime = "INSERT INTO anime (a_name, a_year, a_translated_min, a_translated_max, a_rate_min, a_rate_max, a_edit, a_condition)
                                  VALUES ('$nazov', '$rok', '0', '$pocet', '8', '10', '$preklad', '$stav')";
        mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_vloz_anime);
        $sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime = "SELECT * FROM anime WHERE a_name = '$nazov'";
        $run_sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime);
        $a_id_ziskane = "";

        while ($db_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql_ziskaj_a_id_pridaneho_anime)) {
            $a_id_ziskane = $db_data['a_id'];
        }

        // druha cast formy
        $obrazok = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $uploaddir.$_FILES['obrazok']['name']);
        $zaciatok = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['zaciatok']);
        $koniec = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['koniec']);
        $cas = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['cas']);
        $akihabara = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_to_db, $_POST['akihabara']);

        $sql_vloz_anime_info = "INSERT INTO anime_info (a_id, a_img, a_start, a_stop, a_time_ep, a_akihabara)
                                            VALUES ('$a_id_ziskane', '$obrazok', '$zaciatok', '$koniec', '$cas', '$akihabara')";
        mysqli_query($connect_to_db, $sql_vloz_anime_info);
    } 
    else {
        echo "
            <div class=\"alert alert-success alert-info\" style=\"margin: 10px 0\">
                <a href=\"#\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"close\">&times;</a>
                <strong>POZOR!</strong> Súbor sa nepodarilo nahrať.
            </div>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: just NULL =\  when i vardumped it

Comment: What is the error...?

Comment: `var_dump` what? is `else` executing ?

Comment: your code seem fine to me. Check the permission on the folder in which you image will move.

Comment: @urfusion upload Directory permissions are set to RW for all kind of users

Comment: `else` is executing ?

Comment: yup Else is executing cause in else i gived vardump and error msg

Comment: try to add `/` at aend of $uploadir `$uploaddir = '/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX_FILE_SIZE is in bytes to limit your upload file size to 3M, convert your size to bytes.

```
1024 * (1024 * 3) // 3145728
```

Then change your hidden input to the following

```
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3145728" />
```

Comment: tryed and got 2 mysqli errors            looks like this is problem :o                                              
                     Warning: move_uploaded_file(/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/793392545Untitled.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gj020900/www_nekonomagic/admin/admin-nove-anime.php on line 107

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/home/gj020900/tmp/phpvYH2Ja' to '/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/793392545Untitled.jpg' in /home/gj020900/www_nekonomagic/admin/admin-nove-anime.php on line 107

Comment: now it showing me problem is on line 107 its      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['obrazok']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

Comment: @PatrikHorváth change your upload directory to `$uploaddir = '../www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';`

Comment: same error =\ i dont know why i tried all kind of patchs =\

Comment: The error shows you that the provided path doesn't exists. I don't know your project structure I can only suggest what to do.

Comment: tried $uploaddir = 'res/img/anime/uploads/';  this told me my webhosting provider but now i get no mysqli error and ELSE is executing =(

Comment: The first problem was the `MAX_FILE_SIZE`, now the second problem is, you are not setting the correct path to the uploads directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148673/discussion-between-julekgwa-and-patrik-horvath).

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. You just need to change this:

```
$uploaddir = '/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';
```

to

```
$uploaddir = 'www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';
```

Comment: i think yes cause when i logg in into my Hosting i have www_neko.... directory and it it is stored whole website

Comment: kindly check for confirmation. Because if everything is right then it might be issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your upload directory path line to :

```
$uploaddir = '/www_nekonomagic/res/img/anime/uploads/';
```

You forget to add a backslash to the end of uploads. Do change as above and check if file is being saved in directory. Thanks.

Try to check if temp file is uploaded or not as :

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['obrazok']['tmp_name'])) {
 echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
 echo "Temp file is not uploaded. \r\n";
}
```

Comment: What just I said in comment. :p.

Comment: Sorry B.Desai, I just saw your message. Ya you are right.